# Dump Contents of Python Module loaded in memory

Tags: python, module

I ran the Python REPL tool and imported a Python Module. Can I can dump the contents of that Module into a file? Is this possible? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In what format do you want to write the file?  If you want exactly the same format that got imported, that's not hard -- but basically it's done with a file-to-file copy.  For example, if the module in question is called `blah`, you can do:

```
>>> import shutil
>>> shutil.copy(blah.__file__, '/tmp/blahblah.pyc')
```

Comment: is it possible to copy the module if the module has been loaded, but the file for that module has been deleted?

Comment: Doesn't work? `import itertools; print itertools.__file__` gets `AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute '__file__`

Comment: This works only for modules that do exist as a file (source or bytecode); if the file has never existed as such (but rather only as machine code living in a dynamic library, or as machine code linked into Python's executable) or has been deleted after loading, there is no way to create (or re-create) the file "from scratch" based on memory contents.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like this?

```
http://www.datamech.com/devan/trypython/trypython.py
```

I don't think it is possible, as this is a very restricted environment.
The `__file__` attribute is faked, so doesn't map to a real file

Comment: I am running the repl on my machine's console. After loading the module, I deleted the module's directory. Is there a way to get to copy the module's contents, without the physical file?

Comment: @Bobby, no, there is no way to recover from the deletion mistake in this fashion.

Answer (score 0):

You might get a start by getting a reference to your module object:

```
modobject = __import__("modulename")
```

Unfortunately those aren't pickleable.  You might be able to iterate over `dir(modobject)` and get some good info out catching errors along the way... or is a string representation of `dir(modobject)` itself what you want?